# Rails - Unified sign in form for multiple types of Devise users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

My `Devise` unified sign-in form no longer allows my `Tech` users to log in with either their username or email after implementing the ability to be redirected to a specific page in this case a *profile page*. I can sign-in as a `customer` but I can no longer sign-in as a `tech`. I am receiving the following:

**Invalid login or password.**

Another feature I've implemented is the ability to have users sign with their `usernames` or `email`. Please know each `Devise` user has their own set of controllers and views. For example the `customer` and the `tech` has their own customized view for registration.

- customer: controllers/customer
- tech: controllers/tech

If I were to remove the "*redirect to a specific page*" feature, all `Devise` user models (`customers` and `techs`) are able to log in fine.

> How can I regain the ability of the unified sign-in for both user models while using the `Devise` redirect functionality?

---

Below are the resources used to implement each feature.

- [How To: Allow users to sign in using their username or email address](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address)
- [Unified sign in form for multiple types of Devise users.](https://gist.github.com/jeremyw/5319386)
- [How To: Redirect to a specific page on successful sign up (registration)](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-%28registration%29)

---

**routes**

Rails.application.routes.draw do
    devise_for :customers, controllers: { registrations: 'customers/registrations' }, path: '' #to keep the sign-in page from showing: customer_signup in the url

```
devise_for :techs, controllers: { registrations: 'techs/registrations' }

resources :appointments, :customer_profiles, :service_menus, :services, :tech_profiles
root "home#index"
```

end

---

This `monkey patch` may be why unified sign-in is failing for my `tech` users.

[Unified sign in form for multiple types of Devise users.](https://gist.github.com/jeremyw/5319386)

**config/initializers/devise.rb**

This is located at the bottom of my `devise.rb` file.

```
    module Strategies
      class Base
        def mapping
          # @mapping ||= begin
            mapping = Devise.mappings[scope]
            raise "Could not find mapping for #{scope}" unless mapping
            mapping
          # end
        end
      end
    end
  end

end
```

---

Things I've tried.

- Moving the code `def create` from the `controllers/customer/sessions_controller.rb` to `controllers/customer/registrations_controller.rb` because I thought this is what the `routes` file was calling.

**routes**

`devise_for :customers, controllers: { registrations: 'customers/registrations' }, path: ''`

**controllers/customer/registrations_controller.rb**

```
class Customers::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    # try to authenticate as a Customers
    self.resource = warden.authenticate(auth_options)
    resource_name = self.resource_name

    if resource.nil?
      # try to authenticate as a Tech
      resource_name = :tech
      request.params[:tech] = params[:customer]

      self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options.merge(scope: :tech))
    end

    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end

  protected
    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      new_customer_profile_path
    end

  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:customer).permit(:username, :email, :password)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:customer).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end
end
```

> **EDIT 3:00 PM EST - 7-25-15**

I've added `bind.pry` right before the `resource.nil?`in both the `customers/registrations_controller.rb` and `customers/sessions_controller.rb` but nothing is happening. I've even attempted to force an error by misspelling `pry` to `binding.pry123` and the does not produce an error when attempting to sign in as a `customer` or a `tech`. this leads me to believe that the sign-in process is probably going through another default controller for signing in.

When attempting to sign in as a `tech` I am seeing `Unpermitted parameters: login, password, remember_me`  in the the server logs:

```
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"SOME TOKEN", "customer"=>{"login"=>"s1@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
  Customer Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `customers`.* FROM `customers` WHERE (username = 's1@example.com' OR lower(email) = lower('s1@example.com'))  ORDER BY `customers`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1

Completed 401 Unauthorized in 4ms

Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"SOME TOKEN", "customer"=>{"login"=>"s1@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}

Unpermitted parameters: login, password, remember_me

  Rendered customers/shared/_links.html.erb (4.9ms)
  Rendered customers/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (11.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 239ms (Views: 238.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

---

> **EDIT 11:20 PM July 27, 2015**

What I've failed to include is the following files relating to Devise.

**application controller**

```
require "customer_sanitizer.rb"
  require "tech_sanitizer.rb"

  protected

  def devise_parameter_sanitizer
    if resource_class == Customer
      CustomerParameterSanitizer.new(Customer, :customer, params)
    elsif resource_class == Tech
      TechParameterSanitizer.new(Tech, :tech, params)
    else
      super
    end
  end
```

**lib/customer_sanitizer.rb**

```
class CustomerParameterSanitizer < Devise::ParameterSanitizer

  def sign_up
    default_params.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end

  def sign_in
    default_params.permit(:username, :email)
  end

  def account_update
    default_params.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end

end
```

**lib/tech_sanitizer.rb**

```
class TechParameterSanitizer < Devise::ParameterSanitizer

  def sign_up
    default_params.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end

  def sign_in
    default_params.permit(:username, :email)
  end

  def account_update
    default_params.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end

 end
```

---

If I were to enable the this in the routes:

```
devise_for :customers, controllers: { sessions: 'customers/sessions' }
devise_for :techs, controllers: { sessions: 'techs/sessions }
```

...I can use the unified login. But if I were to register, it would not redirect to the custom profile page.

Commenting out the previous route setting and enabling this:

```
devise_for :customers, controllers: { registrations: 'customers/registrations' }
devise_for :techs, controllers: { registrations: 'techs/registrations' }
```

...I can register for an account then be redirected to a custom profile page after a successful registration but I lose the ability of the unified signin.

According to the logs, it states unpermitted parameters. Is there a to override/whitelist the strongparams?

---

Please let me know if there is any other practical solution for a unified sign-in field which would allow a `user` to log in with either their e-mail or username. Also the ability to to go to a custom profile page after registration.